# Accessing echo'd data in bash

Tags: bash, echo

I'm currently using a code written in bash + C + possibly python, which returns a series of values in a file.  It also echoes lots of values that it produces as part of the calculation.

I've got a script that modifies the input file and runs the program, which works fine, but is there a way to search the lines that it echoes (something like a grep script)?

Comment: Could you redirect the output either to a file or pipe, then simply grep?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert here, but try running your script (the one that produces a lot of echoes) like this:

```
/path/to/myScript.sh > /tmp/myScript.log
```

and then check/grep/tail the log file.

Comment: I knew there'd be an easy answer!  That's great, thanks for the advice.